# Why am i not receiving serial data in visual studios but i am in putty?

Tags: vb.net, serial-port, arduino

Lets say i have this simple arduino program:

```
int i=0;

void setup(void){
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  i++;
  Serial.print(i);
  delay(500);
}
```

It works, prints data in the arduino monitor, and everything is good on its end. I even tried in putty (with same baud and COM as in my vb app) and all the data shows up fine.

Then lets say i have this simple vb console application :

```
Module Module1
    Private WithEvents objSerial As New System.IO.Ports.SerialPort("COM3")


    Sub Main()

        objSerial.BaudRate = 9600
        objSerial.Open()
        Console.ReadKey()
        objSerial.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub objSerial_DataReceived(sender As Object, e As IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles objSerial.DataReceived
        Console.Write(objSerial.ReadExisting)
    End Sub
End Module
```

I found this simple vb program off of youtube and the guy is doing a very similar thing. Except it works for him and does not for me. I have the proper baud rate and COM port selected. I don't think i need a handshake, as the guy on YouTube used this exact code and it worked fine. I'm stuck and really don't know what is wrong here.
Thank you for any help provided!

And i am also pretty new to this stuff so if there is any info i left out, if you let me know i will be quick to comment.

Also, i really doubt this is it but I am using the free VS express, does that for some reason not allow you to use serial port data?

---

JimmyD had the answer to the problem.
final working code:

```
Module Module1
    Private WithEvents objSerial As New System.IO.Ports.SerialPort("COM3")
    Sub Main()

        objSerial.BaudRate = 9600
        objSerial.Handshake = IO.Ports.Handshake.RequestToSend
        objSerial.ReadTimeout = 500
        objSerial.Open()
        Console.ReadKey()
        objSerial.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub objSerial_DataReceived(sender As Object, e As IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles objSerial.DataReceived
        Console.Write(objSerial.ReadExisting)
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: You should mark JimmyD's answer as the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that you don't need to use handshake. I had a similar problem once and handshake did the trick. Try adding the following codes in your Sub Main()

```
objSerial.ReadTimeout = 500
objSerial.Handshake = IO.Ports.Handshake.RequestToSend
```

Also express edition is capable of reading serial data from ports.

Also here is a tutorial that I found online, check it out and see if it helps:
[Reading Arduino data with VB.NET](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=40326.0)

Comment: That pretty much *guarantees* he'll never get anything, Arduino doesn't provide any handshake signals.  Only Handshake.None is appropriate.  Only ever set the ReadTimeout *after* ensuring that basic communication is functional.

Comment: express wont let me use Handshake. I get an error compiling it. It says "Handshake is not declared. It might be due to its protection level"

Comment: How would i use that in the code? just putting those two lines in gets me errors. Do i need to define handshake as something first? sorry i am new

Comment: Below objSerial.BaudRate = 9600. I just created a test program and entered your code exactly as it appears with the new two lines and didn't get any errors. Can you describe the errors your are getting.

Comment: I also edited my answer and added a link. Check it out

Comment: Thank you so much, this has really been frustrating me the last couple days. All i had to do was put those two lines in you gave me but change handshake.requesttosend to IO.Ports.Handshake.RequestToSend. I love you. Also, what is the point of the readtimeout = 500. Just out of pure curiosity

Comment: readtimeout is used to determine how long will your program wait for a response in milliseconds. You don't want your program to wait forever if the device is not responding. If there is a good connection, 500 more than enough to get a response.